# Copy a views video feed into another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a framework that provides video feed coming from a camera.

You can set the view its using to show the video feed like this:

```
 [[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.myView];
```

I want to have two views each playing back the video feed simultaneously. How can I copy the content of the myView object to another view?

Comment: Without knowing the framework, you can't get an answer.

Comment: I disagree, my question is simply how to duplicate a views content, something which shouldn't depent on a framework. The framework merely provides it.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of, not knowing the framework, its functions, etc. I can't think of a single way this is answerable, when all thats known is what you want to do and `[[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.myView];`